# PhpStorm recognizes code changes on Linux too slow

Tags: php, linux, performance, ide, phpstorm

I'm having problems with PhpStorm which realizes too late, that former errors are solved, when I type in the fix. So for example: I'm writing a for-loop and PhpStorm complains about its empty body. When I now type in something, it requires PhpStorm about 5-10 seconds to realize: Oh, it isn't empty anymore! And just now it removes the complain mark.

So my question is, do you developers face the same problem with PhpStorm under Linux? And if yes, what's your solution? It's really annoying, because you wonder, what's wrong just to see, oh, it's just too slow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to increase the amount of memory allocated to PhpStorm?

Comment: Are the files you're working with stored locally? Any symlinks?

Comment: @TomUdding Yes, it's at 2GB now.

Comment: @Ástþór yes, composer project, no symlinks

Comment: @LukasWerner that's strange. It looks like IDE is unable to detect changes on HDD in real time. Do you have any file-system software that might be causing this? Is it a virtual linux machine?